# How to set a style class for a column in Vaadin Grid?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-grid

I'd like to assign a style class to a column in `Grid`. The `Column` class does not provide an `addStyleName` method that other Vaadin components do. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can only set an `CellStyleGenerator` or `RowStyleGenerator` for the grid. To set a class for a column, you have to do this:

```
grid.setCellStyleGenerator(new CellStyleGenerator() {
    @Override
    public String getStyle(CellReference cell) {
        if ("myProperty".equals(cell.getPropertyId()))
            return "my-style";
        else
            return null;
    }
});
```

There can be only single `CellStyleGenerator` for single `Grid`. I often have complex code that configures the grid, and I configure it column by column. I use this utility class, that enables me to do so (requires Java8):

```
/**
 * A {@link CellStyleGenerator}, that enables you to set <code>CellStyleGenerator</code>
 *  independently for each column. It also has a shorthand method to set a fixed style 
 *  class for a column, which Vaadin currently does not allow to (as of Vaadin 7.6).
 *
 * For more information, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36398300/952135
 * @author http://stackoverflow.com/users/952135
 */
public class EasyCellStyleGenerator implements CellStyleGenerator {

    private Map<Object, List<CellStyleGenerator>> generators;

    @Override
    public String getStyle(CellReference cellReference) {
        if (generators != null) {
            List<CellStyleGenerator> gens = generators.get(cellReference.getPropertyId());
            if (gens != null)
                return gens.stream()
                        .map(gen -> gen.getStyle(cellReference))
                        .filter(s -> s != null)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a generator for a column. Allows generating different style for each cell, 
     * but is called only for the given column.
     */
    public void addColumnCellStyleGenerator(Object propertyId, 
            CellStyleGenerator generator) {
        if (generators == null) // lazy init of map
            generators = new HashMap<>();
        generators.computeIfAbsent(propertyId, k->new ArrayList<>()).add(generator);
    }

    /**
     * Sets a fixed style class(es), that will be used for all cells of this column.
     */
    public void addColumnFixedStyle(Object propertyId, String styleClasses) {
        addColumnCellStyleGenerator(propertyId, cellReference -> styleClasses);
    }

}
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question